# sending file via serversocket

Tags: delphi, serversocket

I try to send a file via sendtext but i can't upload more than 4kb
I send the file via base64 and a string:

```
ServerSocket1.Socket.Connections[listview1.Selected.index].Sendtext('FILE<-+^+->' + encodefile(edit4.text));
```

The encodefile script is:

```
function EncodeFile(const FileName: string): AnsiString;
var
  stream: TMemoryStream;
begin
  stream := TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    stream.LoadFromFile(Filename);
    result := EncodeBase64(stream.Memory, stream.Size);
  finally
    stream.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Under the 4kb it works perfect how can i fix this?

Comment: Does it crash? Truncate the file to the first 4096 bytes? 4096 bytes in the file, or 4096 base64 characters? What's in the EncodeBase64 function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like any other socket operation, `SendText()` is not guaranteed to transfer the entire requested data in a single operation, even when using the socket in blocking mode.  The return value reports how many **bytes**, not **characters** were actually accepted.  If the return value is smaller than your data, you have to call `SendText()` again for the remaining unsent data.  So you need to call `SendText()` (actually, it is better to use `SendBuf()` directly) in a loop, eg:

```
uses
  ..., ScktComp, Winsock;

function SendTextToSocket(Socket: TCustomWinSocket; const S: AnsiString): Boolean;
var
  Data: PAnsiChar;
  DataLen, Sent: Integer;
begin
  Result := False;
  Data := PAnsiChar(S);
  DataLen := Length(S);
  while DataLen > 0 do
  begin
    Sent := Socket.SendBuf(Data^, DataLen);
    if Sent = SOCKET_ERROR then
    begin
      if WSAGetLastError <> WSAEWOULDBLOCK then
        Exit;
    end
    else if Sent = 0 then
    begin
      Exit;
    end else
    begin
      Inc(Data, Sent);
      Dec(DataLen, Sent);
   end;
  end;
  Result := True;
end;
```

```
SendTextToSocket(ServerSocket1.Socket.Connections[ListView1.Selected.Index], 'FILE<-+^+->' + EncodeFile(Edit4.Text));
```

Comment: This function has much error so do you think the next script is also good? ServerSocket1.Socket.Connections[listview1.Selected.index].sendbuf(Data^, DataLen);